# Winforms - Unable to focus the opening C# exe after closing the C# dll

Tags: c#, winforms

When the dll is launched,an object of the dll is created and a method which is in the dll is called from exe which will load the form(code to load form is in dll)
When the dll is closed focus goes to other open application(notepad,Visual studio,..etc) for a fraction of second and then comes back to the exe.

This happens when i click on visual studio and then immediately launch exe and then open dll and close it.(Focus goes to visual studio and then to the exe)

Issue does not occur when exe is launched and kept for say a min and then open the dll and close, focus is on exe immediately and not in visual studio.

Comment: If you pop up a window then it is very important that you have *another* window that can get the focus when you close the popup.  If there isn't one then the OS has to find another window to move into the foreground.  That necessarily will be the window of another app, like VS.  And things start to act funny, whether a new window you create after that can move into the foreground or will be overlapped by the window of that other app depends on timing and user input.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Disposing the main form(form.dispose()) of the dll in dll was causing the issue.Removing that line resolved the issue.